# Is mean of means a correct approach?

Tags: anova, mixed-model, mean, method-comparison

I need to compare a certain body value between several groups of people.

The value for each person is a mean of several measurement itself.

The simplest solution would be to compute an ANOVA between the groups, but I'm not so satisfied with this solution, because I'd loose all the information about the variability of the data in the single person.

I would like to understand how being in a certain group influences the average value for an individual, accounting for the variability in the individual. Does it make sense?

I expect not to see differences among individuals of the same group and to see differences among the groups.

What would you suggest?

Comment: What do your data look like ? You have serveral measurements for each individual of each group ? And you're talking about the means of theses measurements ?

Comment: each person has several measurements taken along the day. From these I compute mean, median, sd, CI for each person. Every person then belong to a group and I want to compare the mean value among these groups to see if it's really different.

Comment: Ok. Do you know the SAS language or the R language for mixed models ?

Comment: a bit of R but i'm confident with programming in general

Comment: Ok. But finally I've written an answer without resorting to software language.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. I'd like to add some R/SAS outputs to demonstrate my claim, but currently I'm really too busy.

Comment: yep, also an R example of the algorithm would make it easier to understand for the less maths savvy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are repeated measurements for each individual.

You say that these measurements are taken along a day. *If you are not assuming that the order of the measurements has an importance*, then a common way to model your entire dataset consists in attributing an exchangeable multivariate normal to the series of measurements for each individual $j$ of each group $i$, with a mean $\mu_i$ depending on the group.

If the correlation between the measurements is nonnegative, then the above model is equivalent to a mixed nested two-way ANOVA model with a fixed group effect and a random individual effect: $$y_{ijk} = \mu_i + \gamma_{ij} + \epsilon_{ijk}$$ where $\gamma_{ij} \sim {\cal N}(0, \sigma_b^2)$ is the random effect for individual $j$ in group $i$ and $\epsilon_{ijk} \sim {\cal N}(0,\sigma^2)$ are the residual terms. This can be interpreted by saying that $\mu_i$ is the theoretical mean of group $i$ and $\mu_i + \gamma_{ij}$ is the theoretical mean of individual $j$ in group $i$.

*If the design is balanced* (same number of individual per group and same number of repeated measurements per individual), there is a least-squares approach providing an exact  confidence interval about your parameter of interest $\mu_1-\mu_2$, *and this interval is exactly the same as the "Student" confidence interval obtained from the two samples $\bar y_{1j\bullet}$ and $\bar y_{2j\bullet}$ of the individual means*.

Comment: Hi thanks again for your answer, at the time I didn't have the knowledge to understand it. Now it's a bit better as my statistics is improving. If I understood well the coefficent of mu should be tell me how much a group influences the mean of a person? while gamma should not change?
Anyway I would be glad if you would put an algorithmic implementation of your answer, better if in R. My biggest question is: how should I tab the values to put them in the model? mu should be a dataset with a column for the means of each individual and a column for group ID? what should I put in gamma and eta?

Comment: BTW, I have more than two groups, I will edit the question.

Comment: Actually the data is ordered (its one misuration every minute), but I think the order it's not fundamental.

Comment: If you provide a small sample of your data we can easily show you some code on how to run mixed models in R.

Comment: Hi I provided a more detailed and general question on the research problem I'm trying to solve! here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81290/how-to-model-influence-of-group-on-mean-and-variance-of-heart-rate-in-patients-w

It's hard to pass you the data since I got hundreds of measurements per person!

Thanks a lot!